# How to get POSTED data in php script?

Tags: php, android

I am working on an android application in which I POST data using following code segments.

```
 public void postData()
         {    
             try 
             {
              // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header 
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/check/justprint.php");  
          // Add your data 
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "jaydeepsinh jadeja"));  
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "00000000000000"));  
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

                // Execute HTTP Post Request  
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
                String text = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());          
                   Log.i("","response = "+text); 
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {  
                Log.e("Error:",e+"");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {  
                Log.e("Error:",e+"");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
         }
```

My main requirement is that get this values in php script and display on web page.
Is there any way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php

```
echo $_POST['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think thatyou could get them like this

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
```

and then you can display them. If this doesn't work, try

```
$filename = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."logging.txt";

if(isset($_POST)){
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        file_put_contents($filename, "key[$key] - value[$value] post \n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

and see if a file called logging.txt is created in the dir of that script